# Laravel Collection ( not Eloquent) to Object

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

Is it possible to return an object from a Laravel collection ?

```
$originalArr =[
    'foo' =>'bar',
   'foo2' => 'bar2'

]

$coll=collect($originalArr)->reject(function($item){

    // do something
});


// now I can convert the collection to an array... but to an object?
$arr = $coll->toArray();

// array
dump($arr)

// but what if I want to have an object ?  I have to do 
$object  = (object) $arr;


dump ($object) 


//So you can access the attributes like  $object->foo.
```

But this seems fairly stupid... First make a collection , then convert to an array and then once again convert to an object.

Is there a more efficient way?

**Edit**

Alright I input an array I will get an array back , but what If I input an object ?

```
$origalObject = (object) $originalArr =[
        'foo' =>'bar',
       'foo2' => 'bar2'

    ];
```

... And do the same , laravel will give me back an array.
And I have to cast it again to an Object.  That is a lot of extra code if dealing with objects. Sure I can build a simple function for this .. but why is it not build in Laravel?

Comment: A Collection is an object? If you mean return the individual items as an object: as long as you don't put objects in the collection, it's not possible to return objects from it without explicit casting like you do in your example. You use an array as input, it won't automagically turn into an object without you telling it should.

Comment: Thanks for replying , what if my input in an object ?  I surely want an object back?  Laravel collection will give back an array.  So I am wondering why there is not a method toObject.  That's all.

Comment: Tbh, I've never had this issue. If I put an object into a collection, I get an object back. This code doesn't work on 3v4l but should work fine in a Laravel project: https://3v4l.org/Va1Uc

Comment: `toArray()` converts the collection to an array that contains all collection items, which can be objects. Since a collection can contain multiple items (arrays, objects, etc.), what would you expect from `toObject()`? And your code `$object  = (object) $arr;` is  wrong because it would cast the array containing your actual object to an object therefore adding your actual object as a property of the newly cast object. To access the first item in a collection you can use `$coll->first();`, which in your case would return your object.

Comment: @Loek   : Object in ..will not get an object out...  https://3v4l.org/HWcoZ

Comment: @Remul  : Thanks for replying mate !  On an one-dimensional array it will return the first (key) value...  It will not give me back the object.

Comment: @Paolo_Mulder Just now noticed that your code for creating the collection is missing the square brackets. `collect([$origalObject])`, otherwise laravel will iterate over all your object properties and add them as an array. See [here](https://implode.io/GKK4qH) and [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#creating-collections)

Answer (score 0):

The [`toArray()` method](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php#L1943) isn't a cast but actually just returns the internal array (after checking for `Arrayable` elements).

So, even if the collection had a `toObject()` method it would simply `return (object)$this->toArray().` just as you did in your code.

You could create a push request and add it as a convenience method, but you should create an issue first to see if there people are intrested.

Alternatively, for simple cases like in your example you could just use the default PHP array functions (e.g. `array_filter`), so you have one fewer step.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , much appreciated. (First)ToObject would be a fantastic extra to laravel...  I will take a look. Pretty sure I will not be the only one with this...